# Is there any way I can use less memory and make the run time shorter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

heres the prompt:
construct a numeral triangle according to the following rules:

1. the first row contains a starting number
2. each of the new rows has one more number than prev
3. each number is a specified larger amount than the last
4. before adding to the "triangle", make sure all the characters of multi digit numbers are added together to form a one digit number
5. return the sum of the last row in the "triangle"

heres my answer: the first function takes care of the fourth requirement, it adds the digits of a number up until there is only one digit. example: 123 = 1+2+3 = 6. The second function takes in s (starting value), d (increments), and r (number of rows). It creates boxnum, which are the total number of boxes in the triangle and how many times I must add the increment to the previous value. if r = 99,999, the entire code will loop that many times and it will exceed the time limit which is my problem. i also have a problem with storage, because each value is being appended to the list when in reality i only need the last row. I'm not sure how to re-write and cut down my code.

```
def multidigit(x):
  numsum = 0 
  if x < 9:
    return(x)
  else:
    for number in str(x):
      numsum += int(number)
    if numsum > 9:
      return(multidigit(numsum))
    else:
      return(numsum)

def sumOfLastRow(s, d, r):
  rowslist = []
  rowslist.append(multidigit(s))
  incrementnum = s
  boxnum = 0
  for i in range(r+1):
    boxnum = boxnum + i
  for i in range(boxnum-1):
    incrementnum = incrementnum + d
    if incrementnum > 9:
      incrementnum = multidigit(incrementnum)
    rowslist.append(incrementnum)
  splitlist = rowslist[-r:]
  rowslist.clear()
  total = 0
  for i in range(len(splitlist)):
    total = total + splitlist[i]
  return(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if x < 9:
>     return(x)
> ```

That doesn't look right.
Probably you started out with an infinite loop bug on the x == 9 case,
and then tacked on the final `else` to paper over it.
I bet you wanted

```
if x <= 9:
    return int(x)
```

Much simpler to

```
return sum(map(int, str(x)))
```

You could use a similar idiom when computing `total`.

---

> ```
> for i in range(r+1):
>     boxnum = boxnum + i
> ```

There's no need to loop, here, as a quadratic closed form solution is available.
https://dev.to/alisabaj/the-gauss-sum-and-solving-for-the-missing-number-996